# TypeScirpt の for...of 文で [Symbol.iterator]() が必要と言われる

Tags: javascript, typescript

## 概要

forof文を書こうと思ったら、`[Symbol.iterator]()` が必要だと怒られた。

```js
const test = [
{ code: 0, name: "北海道" },
{ code: 1, name: "東京都" },
{ code: 2, name: "大阪府" },
];

function createPrefOptionsHTML(prefs: object) {
 const optionsStrs = [];
 for (const pref of prefs ) {          <= error
  optionsStrs.push(
   `<option name="${pref.name}" value="${pref.code}>${pref.name}</option>`
  );
 }
const prefSelector = document.getElementById("areaSelector")?.querySelector(".prefectures");
prefSelector!.innerHTML = optionsStrs.join("");
createPrefOptionsHTML(test);
```

どう記述すればいいのでしょう

Answer (score 0, accepted):

引数 `prefs` の型を `object` にしているのが原因です。

`object` だけでは [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) に使える反復可能オブジェクトであることを表現できていません。使うのが配列であれば、配列型を指定すれば問題のエラーは消えます。

```js
prefs: object[]
```

ただし、これでは別の箇所でまたエラーか警告が出るでしょう。`pref.name` などとしてプロパティにアクセスしている箇所です。これらのプロパティが存在することを `object` では表現できていません。これにも対処すると、例えば以下のようになります。

```
type Pref = { code: number; name: string }

function createPrefOptionsHTML(prefs: Pref[]) {
```